# Days calculation of a particular year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have few contracts against which I need to recognize the revenue for which i need to check the number of days each year would have for a multi-year deal. How to do that?

Eg. Start Date: 1 April, 2023; End Date:31 March, 2026
In this I have ~255 days in 2023, 365 days in 2024, 365 days in 2025 and 90 days in 2026. How to find these deatils dynamically?

Not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Year `2023` should be 275 days , `2024` will be 366, `2025` will be 365 and `2026` will be 90. Year `2024` is  a leap year!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, TEXT(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1),"yyyy"),
     φ, UNIQUE(α),
     HSTACK(φ, MMULT(N(φ=TOROW(α)),α^0)))
```

---

Or Using <kbd>PIVOTBY()</kbd> applicable to `Beta Users`

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, YEAR(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1)),
     PIVOTBY(α,,α,COUNTA,,0))
```

---

Or, using <kbd>GROUPBY()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, YEAR(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1)),
     GROUPBY(α,α, COUNTA,,0))
```

---

Using <kbd>BYROW()</kbd> but without <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> construct:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, YEAR(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1)),
     φ, UNIQUE(α),
     HSTACK(φ, BYROW(N(φ=TOROW(α)),SUM)))
```

---

**Edit:**

As suggested by **[Terry W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11768364/terry-w)** Sir for more clear understanding of the use of variables within <kbd>LET()</kbd> function with some relatable words that are easier to use and can be identified, hence amending it.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _listOfYears, TEXT(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1),"yyyy"),
     _uniqueloy, UNIQUE(_listOfYears),
     HSTACK(_uniqueloy, MMULT(N(_uniqueloy=TOROW(_listOfYears)),_listOfYears^0)))
```

---

Where:

- `_listOfYears` --> Returns a sequence of years between the given `Start_Date` & `End_Date` (Note that: Using `_listOfYears` because it actually returns a list of dates but when wrapped within <kbd>TEXT()</kbd> or <kbd>YEAR()</kbd> function it generates a list of years.
- `_uniqueloy` --> Returns the unique list of the above years returned from `_listOfYears`
- And the final product is a matrix multiplication of two arrays!

---

Also, one can use <kbd>YEAR()</kbd> function in place of <kbd>TEXT()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _listOfYears, YEAR(SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1)),
     _uniqueloy, UNIQUE(_listOfYears),
     HSTACK(_uniqueloy, MMULT(N(_uniqueloy=TOROW(_listOfYears)),_listOfYears^0)))
```

---

For Older Versions:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=YEAR($B$1)+(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,YEAR($B$2)-YEAR($B$1)+1))-1)
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(YEAR($B$1+(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,$B$2-$B$1+1))-1))=D1))
```

---

Comment: brilliant answer, just a suggestion, replace the special character you have been using in the LET function with some common words that are easier for others to use (or less confusing for those who are not that experienced with Excel). For example, use 'Datelist' instead of 'α' and 'UniqueYearList' instead of 'φ' in this example.

Comment: @TerryW Sir, updated thanks for the suggestions and guidance !

Comment: thank you @MayukhBhattacharya - can you please explain what  YEAR($B$1)+(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,YEAR($B$2)-YEAR($B$1)+1))-1) is doing?  - want to understand the logic so I can explain someone if needed

Comment: Have you entered the formula if so then what do you get? And also have you tried to evaluate the formula or not? This part of the formula creates a reference of `0`,`1`,`2`,`3` and adding the start year it returns the required years `(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,YEAR($B$2)-YEAR($B$1)+1))-1)` Also if you are not using `MS365`/`Excel 2021/`Excel 2019` you will need to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode. moreover if you are using `Excel 2007` or `Excel 2010 or 2013` you will need to select the range of 4 cells and enter the formula to return the output as its array formula

Answer (score 0):

And for those having access to Beta Chanel of Excel:

`=LET(s,SEQUENCE(1+A2-A1,,A1),GROUPBY(YEAR(s),s,COUNT,,0))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, just the simple method using the days() function which evidently is not inclusive on how it calculates so you need to account for that:

[image]